# Mudar a linha de cor de acordo com o conteúdo da célula no datagridview

Tags: c#

Tenho um Windows Form que carrega um `DataGridView`, nele tem uma coluna que contém valores positivos e negativos, preciso que quando o valor desta coluna for negativo a linha fique com uma cor diferente.

Como posso fazer isso?

segue o Código:

```
private void ListaGrid()
{
    string strSQL = @"SELECT  
            SA.A1_COD                     AS CODIGO,
            SA.A1_NOME                    AS CLIENTE,
            SA.A1_LC                      AS [LIMITE CREDITO],
            SUM(SE.E1_VALOR)              AS [TOTAL COMPRA],
            SUM(SE.E1_SALDO)              AS [SALDO ABERTO],
            SA.A1_LC - SUM(SE.E1_SALDO)   AS [SALDO LIMITE]
        FROM SA1010 AS SA
        INNER JOIN SE1010 AS SE WITH (NOLOCK) ON SA.A1_COD = SE.E1_CLIENTE
        WHERE SA.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*' AND SE.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
        GROUP BY SA.A1_COD, SA.A1_NOME, SA.A1_LC
        ORDER BY CODIGO";

    comando = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conm);

    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter dados = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);
        DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
        dados.Fill(dtLista);

        DGW_LimiteCredito.DataSource = dtLista;
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Não existem dados a serem encontrados");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você vai iterar por todas as linhas do seu `DataGridView` e comparar o valor da coluna que contém o valor que você quer checar.
Se o valor for negativo, a linha (row) será pintada da cor que você escolher, no exemplo é vermelho.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGW_LimiteCredito.Rows)
{
     if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[/*Index ou nome da coluna com o valor*/].Value) < 0 ) 
     {
         // Se for negativo, fica vermelho
         row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red; 
     }
}
```

Comment: Embora seja legível o que fez, considere deixar uma explicação.

Comment: @LP.Gonçalves É verdade, deixei explicado.

Comment: Muito obrigado deu certinho aqui.